# C++ Call an abstract method from a static method using *this

Tags: c++, class, this, abstract

I am trying to make an abstract class which allows you to call the method `Fun`, which is static, which prints `"Abstract Class"`, however, it is not working, as I am using `*this` in a static method. I am confused on how I can reslove this problem:

```
class A
{
private:
    virtual void __Fun() = 0
    {
        std::cout << "Abstract Class";
    }
    static void _Fun(A &instance)
    {
        instance.__Fun();
    }
public:
    static void Fun()
    {
        _Fun(*this); // 'this' may only be used in nonstatic member functions
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a; // Throws - which is good: class is abstract
    A::Fun(); // Desired result
}
```

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, there is no `this` in a static context.  What is the overall goal here?

Comment: why you are defining a function that is supposed to be pure virtual ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I accidentally cut out the static keyword on two of the functions. Appended now :)

Comment: Ok.  Previous comment updated also!

Comment: You should really try to describe what you are trying to achieve here  as your current implementation makes it hard to extract that information. Refrain from describing the way but only the goal.

Comment: @Joseph See my post. The post you up voted is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myabe what you want is to create not an abstract class, but a class with a private constructor (like a singleton)?

```
class A
{
private:
    A()
    {
    }
    virtual void __Fun()
    {
        std::cout << "Abstract Class";
    }
    static void _Fun(A &instance)
    {
        instance.__Fun();
    }
public:
    static void Fun()
    {
        A a;
        _Fun(a);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a; // Throws - which is good: constructor is private
    A::Fun(); // Desired result
}
```

But then, I'm not sure why do you need such a thing at all, and why do you need virtual functions in it?

Comment: Your example does not contain an abstract class so it has nothing common with the question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just noticed that what the OP really wants is not an abstract class, but a class that can't be instantiated. It's regular practice on SO to propose in an answer something different than the OP originally requested. Even if this is not what the OP asked for in the beginning it proved to be useful.

Comment: I do not see this. He clearly says about an abstract class and his example contains a pure virtual function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, the question was quite vague. I just guessed what the OP wants. The fact that this answer got accepted proves that my guess was correct.

Comment: I am not sure in this.

Answer (score 1):

You may not call method __Fun such way because it requires an instance of the class but in turn you may not create an object of an abstract class.
Also your class definition is invalid because pure specifier can be used only in a member function declaration. The function definition may not have the pure specifier.

To achiev what you want you could write for example

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    virtual void __Fun() = 0;
public:
    static void Fun( A &instance )
    {
        instance.__Fun(); // 'this' may only be used in nonstatic member functions
    }
};

void A::__Fun()
{
    std::cout << "Abstract Class";
}

class B : public A
{
    virtual void __Fun() { A::__Fun(); }
};


int main()
{
    B b; // Throws - which is good: class is abstract
    A::Fun( b ); // Desired result
}
```

Comment: how this thing can possibly work if we have a function that is both _pure virtual_ and _defined_ at the same time, this code doesn't even compiles.

Comment: @user2485710  You are right.